# Python String Substitute Dict: Skip Key and Leave Formatter

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, string-substitution

I am a string substitute that takes a few vaules and was wondering is it possible to skip a key and leave it there, not filling it with a space?

```
s='%(name)s has a %(animal)s that is %(animal_age)s years old'

#skip the animal value
s = s % {'name': 'Dolly', 'animal': 'bird'}#, 'animal_age': 10}

print s
```

#### Expected Output:

```
Dolly has a bird that is %(animal_age)s years old
```

Comment: you mean skip the `animal_age` value here?

Comment: Exactly, is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two `%%` in the string to skip string formatting.:

```
In [169]: s='%(name)s has a %(animal)s that is %%(animal_age)s years old'

In [170]: s % {'name': 'Dolly', 'animal': 'bird', 'animal_age': 10}

Out[170]: 'Dolly has a bird that is %(animal_age)s years old'
```

or using `string.format()`:

```
In [172]: s='{name} has a {animal} that is %(animal_age)s years old'

In [173]: dic = {'animal': 'bird', 'animal_age': 10, 'name': 'Dolly'}

In [174]: s.format(**dic)
Out[174]: 'Dolly has a bird that is %(animal_age)s years old'
```